# How to run Postgres psql "slash" commands using Sequel

Tags: ruby, postgresql, psql, sequel

Using [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel), is it possible to run PostgreSQL "slash" commands, such as `\d`, `\dn` or `\copy table...`?

I tried using

```
DB.run(‘\dn’)
```

but I got a syntax error, because, presumably Sequel is trying to parse the SQL, or Postgres can’t understand the SQL, because these are commands that are handled by the `psql` application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slash commands are features of `psql`, not the server so they're only accessible in `psql`. However, some of them (such as `\copy`) have equivalents that the server does understand and the rest are shortcuts to queries of the system tables. If you run [`psql -E`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> `-E`
>   `--echo-hidden`
>   Echo the actual queries generated by `\d` and other backslash commands. You can use this to study psql's internal operations. This is equivalent to setting the variable `ECHO_HIDDEN` to on.

then you can see the queries and you should be able to use those queries with `DB.run` or `DB.fetch(...).all`. For example:

```
$ psql -E -d...
=# \d
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'table' WHEN 'I' THEN 'index' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','p','v','m','S','f','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
**************************
=# \dt
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'table' WHEN 'I' THEN 'index' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','p','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
**************************
```

Comment: This is the right approach, but you'll want to use `DB.fetch(sql_string).all`, as `DB.run(sql_string)` returns nil.

Comment: @JeremyEvans Thanks, I just added a little update for that.